# SQL Server 2000 Memory Status

Tags: memory, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to get a better idea of how my SQL 2000 instance is using it's memory. I've run DBCC MEMORYSTATUS and I'm hoping someone can give me a better idea of how to interpret the output.

My main concern is the 'Other' section of the buffer distribution. It is currently using by far the most pages at 166,000. Considering that SQL has only about 2GB of availible RAM, the fact that most of that is being used by 'Other' worries me.

Below is the full output . 
I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
Buffer Distribution Buffers  
Stolen      30595
Free        966
Procedures      208
Inram       0
Dirty       8424
Kept        0
I/O         137
Latched     437
Other       166065
```

Comment: You'll probably get more and better answers on serverfault.com - that's where the SQL DBA's hang out...

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your buffer pool aka data cache. From [MS KB 271624](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624)

> **Other**. These are committed pages that do not meet any of the criteria mentioned earlier. Typically, the majority of buffers that meet this criteria are hashed data and index pages in the buffer cache.

This looks *good*: you have 1300MB cached data + indexes which means your queries are hitting RAM not disk.